# How to give a mysql user permission to create and delete database on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

i recently migrated to aws from shared hosting, as i was using php application i chose to use mysql as db.

However i was hosting 3 web applications on 1 ec2 instance, i had to create 3 DB's and 3 User's giving them appropriate fill privilege to their respective DB.

However now the problem is when they login to phpmyadmin they cannot create a database it says `#1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'user_test'`

How should i overcome this?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: Which section should i refer, it would b great if you could help me with a code!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "giving them appropriate fill privilege to their respective DB" - what exact steps or commands did you use for this? Note that you appear to be trying to log in as 'user' but the database is 'user_test' and based on your description, you would want the database name 'user'. More details would help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, login :

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

then just write:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: but the use should only have access to have a look at his created / granted database not  of other, would this work?

Comment: any user should have access to all Privileges for access other users databases, such as root user databases, and that user not required to have access to all Privileges for using it's databases. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Not just view, this command Grant Read/Write Access to selected user.

Comment: The view permission should also not be there

Comment: so you want grant no permissions on selected user.

Comment: I agree with PHP Developer; I was just going to write the same. It's generally a better practice to give the least amount of privileges required for an application, so granting global privileges to a user that only needs access to `user_test` isn't the best example to show someone. At the very least, we should ask the poster for such details before granting such widespread privileges and restrict the new user to only the database and actions that are required.